# How does the Play Store recognize the languages of the app?

Tags: android, google-play

I am currently working on an application that has multiple customers and we build our apk with a build server. Some of our customers has spanish translations, others has russian ones, etc.

I was wondering how Google Play detects which language(s) are part of the application. Is it with:

> values-es

With nothing in the folder

**Or**

> values-es\strings.xml

And 0 or more files in it?

We don't want to show users that the application has a spanish version of it when it really doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When publishing your app at GooglePlay, you have to decide

> which countries and territories you want to distribute to

--> [Determine Country Distribution](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#determine-country)

At runtime,

> Android automatically selects and loads the resources that best match the device.

--> [Resource-Switching in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#resource-switching)

So make sure to have a default version for absolutely every string in 
res/values/strings.xml in order to avoid app crashes
and optionally add folders/resource_files for additional languages,
e.g. values-es/strings.xml

If a string doesn't have to be translated (like 'OK' in many languages), you do not have to provide a version in the respective additional folder.